# Google Sheets Data Validation - How to add multiple values at once?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In google sheets, I'm trying to create a data validation and make a dropdown box with many possible values to select. Previously, there was a way to create the validation by adding your list of values separated by comma but now I only see the option to add values one-by-one. Is this feature gone or what happened?  How do I do this?

[image: Data Validation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose "Dropdown (from a range)":

[image]